# Beer was spilt on my keyboard, most keys work but some don't, is there any hope?

Tags: keyboard, dell-inspiron

I've often had it whereby i've spilt tea on the keyboard, some keys don't work for a couple of days and then wake up again.  A few people online have suggested actually taking the keyboard off and soaking it in water, but that sounds ridiculous, like making the problem worse? It's quite annoying as I was just about to make a claim on my warranty for a different issue and obviously if I start trying to take matters into my own hands, that'll be void.

It's a Dell Inspiron 15, so I don't suppose if anyone has any experience dealing with Dell specifically on this issue?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's ridiculous. If the keyboard isn't plugged in, there is no way to create a short circuit. If you place it in water, all the "sugar" from such beverages will be dissolved. Then you have to dry it very well using some pressurized air or/and use a hairdryer to remove any moisture left.

Comment: Might there already be a short circuit though, and that's why certain keys aren't working?

Comment: Unfortunately there is a high possibility. More often than not sugar creates a layer that doesn't allow a contact to be made. After a few uses, heat generated from your laptop, melts the sugar resulting in a successful electrical connection. That's why after a few days your buttons started to function properly again.

Comment: ah, so is it possible for just certain keys to short circuit, in that sense? or is it an all or nothing scenario? i'm using the laptop now, i know i shouldn't be, but i need it for work

Comment: Even with laptops, keyboards are just parts that can be replaced. You might be able to open up the laptop and clean it (make sure it dries before use). Otherwise you can replace the keyboard.

Comment: It doesn't have to be all or nothing! It is quite possible that some keys simply don't work! You can follow the recipe with the water and the hairdryer to make it work or use an external USB keyboard until you either fix it or buy a new one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keyboard isn't plugged in, there is no way to create a short circuit. If you place it in water, all the "sugar" from such beverages will be dissolved. Then you have to dry it very well using some pressurized air or/and use a hairdryer to remove any moisture left.

If you are in a hurry and have to work on that laptop you can use an external USB keyboard but you can always buy a new keyboard for your laptop.

A search on ebay `Dell <model> keyboard` will give you some results to get an idea on the cost. And also it is very easy to replace your keyboard, so don't be afraid of it.

Comment: thanks for that, i've looked on ebay and they seem fairly cheap, would it void my warranty to change it?

Comment: @MatthewHaworth : So is still in warranty? Probably yes unless you do it quite carefully so that no signs of wear will appear. But anyway, if you want to clean it, you'll have to remove it...